# complex exponential squared (simplification)

Tags: complex-numbers

When finding an arbitrary DTFT, a simplification step involves finding: $$(1-\alpha e^{-j\omega}) ^2$$
How is the $(e^{-j\omega})(e^{-j\omega})$ bit calculated?  Instinct is telling me that $e^{-j(\omega+\omega)} = e^{-j2\omega} $ but I am second guessing myself.  Thank you.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The same algebric rules valid for real numbers and exponential also holds for complex numbers and exponential.